# Unobstructive XML commenting

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sandcastle

I've created a project and started work on documenting it. Sandcastle uses XML comments to create a nice help file, but the XML comments leave the code nearly unreadable. Each class I write now starts off something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary of Foo class
/// </summary>
public class Foo
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Summary of bar</summary>
    public int bar;
    ///<summary>
    ///Summary of bat</summary>
    public String bat;

    ///<summary>
    ///Summary of constructor</summary
    ///<param name="a">description of a</param>
    ///<param name="b">description of b</param>
    public Foo(int a, int b)
    ....
}
```

Is there any way to clean this code up, while leaving enough information to create a nice help file?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look through here if you're unsure...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx

And here's their example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288481(v=vs.71).aspx

But that's honestly exactly how it's supposed to look. I generally keep everything minimized unless I'm making a change to it. But full XML documentation like that can be a godsend if new developers are joining your project.

Just fight through it and hopefully learn to love it?

Comment: That's too bad, because some of my methods have upwards of 10 parameters, so you can imagine how that looks. Basically an entire screen taken over by comments that someone reading the code won't need.

Comment: That's why they're all collapsible. Write it, collapse, move on. If you need to make changes then expand and do so. I would never leave all the comments open, the document would be as you say "unreadable". ctrl-M-O (collapse all) is your friend! In all honestly I felt the same thing way back when I started using it, made everything feel so bloated. Now I leave nothing without it's XML and sandcastle works beautifully to generate documentation.

Comment: I look forward to the day when the IDE will format this all nicely for us (while we're not actively editing it, of course). In the meantime, I've actually read it so much I don't really notice the formatting.

Comment: @HH well having 10 parameter is a little to much, the problem there is probably lack of refactoring not XML documentation :)

Comment: @Wrightboy, the sandcastle docs are great, no arguments there. The issue I have is that I might not be the only person editing this code in the future and I don't want to assume anything about the IDE they might be using. (Although collapsible comments are pretty standard I think).

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension for that<sup>*</sup>:

> [Hide/Show Comments](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/03141ea7-c35e-4533-b05b-9e60545e93eb?SRC=VSIDE)

<sup>*<sub>I haven't tried this myself but it looks like it might help you.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

The [include tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h8dy30z.aspx) allows you to put most of your documentation in separate files. Typically this is used to reuse common documentation across various implementations of a virtual or interface member, but it could also be used to simply separate out documentation.